# Start a Docker volume and give it a name

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I want to know how to start a Docker container with a named volume. I've tried this

```
docker run -it --name container1 -v path:path --name volumename image bin/bash
```

But the container was also named `"volumename"`

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You should create your volume first with `docker volume create volumename` and then use it when running container with `docker run -it --name container1 -v volumename:path image bin/bash`. If you look at the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) you won't find a way to create named volume while creating container.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you don't have an existing image then you have to create one by using:

```
docker volume create --name [volume name]
```

For instance:

```
docker volume create --name namedvolume
```

If you did this you can check if it has been created. Just type:

```
docker volume ls
```

You did all right, if it shows your created volume.
Last step:

```
docker run -v [volume name]:[container directory]
```

With a directory:

```
docker run -it --name container -v data-volume:/data image /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I tried it and it works
But in that case how do I specify the path to my local directory ? 
I used to specify it with the command when I use path:path but if I use volumename:path from which directory it will take my datas from the host machine?

Comment: @LaQuica If you do `docker volume inspect volumename` you can see the mountpoint (somewhere in the Docker space, probably `/var/lib/docker/volumes/volumename/_data`). If you want to use your local directory, then you need to use [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). For example, if you do `docker container run -it -v /tmp:/var image` you would bind you local `/tmp` directory to `/var` path/directory in the container, so if you make a change in the `/var` directory, it will affect the content of your local `/tmp` directory.